# Contains and equals

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm a little befuddled by some code:

```
for (AbstractItem item : mSetOfItems) {
        if (item.equals(pPrimaryItem))
        {
            System.out.println("Contains? " + mSetOfItems.contains(pPrimaryItem));
        }
}
```

How could it be possible that item.equals(pPrimaryItem) resolves as true, and mSetOfItems.contains(pPrimaryItem) resolves as false? Because that's what I'm seeing in my code.

In other words, if I iterate through my set, I can find an element equal to my test element. But if I use contains, my test elements is not reported being in the set. I'm baffled because I thought contains used equals. What could I be overlooking?

Comment: What is the type of your set? Is it a built in Collection, and is it generic and with what type?

Comment: It is a HashSet... I'm getting the picture from the answers that I need to override hashCode, not just equals...

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much a rule for Java. Equality with hashCode() should always match equality with equals(), so if you define one, you should define the other.

Comment: Yup. I think the JavaDoc for contains() threw me off the scent:
"Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))." Forgot about equals vs hashCode.

Comment: Defining a hashCode method consistent with the equals method indeed solved my problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Rajiv M: Almost. If two objects are equal, their hashcodes should be equal. The opposite does not have to be true. `public int hashCode(){ return 1 }` is valid, although terrible for use within any data structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't give the type of `mSetOfItems`, but I'm guessing that `AbstractItem` overrides `.equals()` but not `.hashcode()`. This is bad.

If `mSetOfItems` uses hashcode for lookup, which it could based on its type, you'll get the behavior you described.

Your assumption is that `.contains()` is implemented with iteration and `.equals()`. There's no list interface which guarantees that.

Comment: Or that the implementations are not consistent.

Answer (score 6):

What is the implementation of `mSetOfItems`?

- If it's a tree, it could be that your comparison function returns inconsistent values.
- If it's a hash, it could be that your `equals()` returns true for objects with different hash codes, or that the object's `hashCode()` has changed since it was inserted into the set.

Answer (score 3):

If your set is a `TreeSet` or some other set where you're using a custom comparator, then you could see this if the comparator was broken, either by not returning a valid sorted order or by having objects that are actually equal compare unequal.  When the set internally looks up an element and uses the comparator, it would make a wrong choice and not see the element.

If your set is a `HashSet`, your hash function could be broken and cause two objects that are equal to have different hash code.  Internally as the `HashSet` uses the object's hash code to figure out where to look, it might end up looking in the wrong bucket.

Alternatively, if you store objects in a `Set` of any sort and then modify them, you might end up breaking some internal invariant of the `Set`.  For instance, if you store something in a `HashSet` and then change its value, it will be in the wrong bucket, and if you have a `TreeSet` and change the value it may appear in the wrong spot in sorted order.

If you are concurrently modifying the set, it's possible that you might have added the element in another thread but not had any guarantees that the operation that made that change be visible in another thread.  The second thread would then not see the element even if it were added.

Answer (score 2):

Check the hashcode() method of your class

Answer (score 2):

If `mSetOfItems` is a `java.util.HashTable` (or similar 'Hash' Collection, Set, etc) then you must implement `hashCode()` as well. `boolean contains(Object elem)` will first try to find the passed object by calculating its hash and retrieving it in the Collection. Once contains finds something, it will then use the equals method to verify that the two objects are the same objects according to your implementation.

If not properly overridden, `hashCode()` will return an unpredictable `int` that is usually the integer representation of the internal address of the object itself. This will always be different for two distinct objects no matter the the values of their instance variables. If not overridden, contains won't be able to find it any objects...

When implementing hashCode() remind that:

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Also, make sure that you properly overridden the equals function by respecting its signature:

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj);
```

Comment: Good info.  To complement your answer, here is a post with some additional details on implement hashcode, mainly that tools like Eclipse can be used to generate a hashcode method, and that libraries like Apache Commons provide builders for hashcodes.  http://piotrjagielski.com/blog/more-maintainable-hashcode-and-equals-using-apache-commons/